# gzgrep help in multiple large archives - solaris

Tags: unix, grep, solaris

In solaris- i need to perform a gzgrep of archives.  But i need to filter so not searching ALL the archives- maybe just files with '09.30-12' in the name.. then i want to search IN that particular file or files for a particular expression.  I have this close.. but it takes WAY too long as its searching unnecessary files first and matching on those.. then moving onto the October archives and finding what i need in them. I need to basically search any files in which filename contains 'x' then look in those files for text 'y' and output to > fileoutput.  Perhaps just change the *.gz to just match on a set of files?? i cannot figure out how though.  Any help is MUCH appreciated.

Something like this works- but i get way too much output and it takes way too long.

gzgrep 'firstexpression' *.gz > /fileoutput.file

Answer (score 2):

> maybe just files with '09.30-12' in the name..

You could say:

```
gzgrep 'firstexpression' *09.30-12*.gz > fileoutput.file
```

or

```
gzgrep pattern_to_search *filename_pattern*.gz > outfile
```